# How to find position of char in Two-dimensional lists?

Tags: python, list

I need to find position of specific char in two-dimensional list

I tired

```
list=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
print(list.index("c"))
```

and

```
print(list.index[0]("c"))
```

But it does not work:
**print(list.index("c"))

builtins.ValueError: 'c' is not in list**

Comment: `list[0].index('c')` - but better to iterate to find. Aside, please choose variable names which are not also object names.  Currently, your variable `list` is overwriting the builtin function.

Comment: You need to iterate over the 2-dimensional list until you find a row where `"c" in row` is true, and then find the index within that row.

Comment: @S3DEV I changed that but there is same error.

Comment: @JohnColemanI know that there is that solution but isn´t there something like this code?

Comment: This type of code is only relevant when you already know the row, in which case there is really no problem since calling index on that row should work. Maybe you are mistaken about "c" being in a given row.

Comment: @Dominik - Then something else is wrong, because that will work given the list you have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this way:

Explain: your *list* is a nested list containing sublists, so you have to go one level deeper to get the *value* that's you're interested.

**Note** - please avoid using built-in *list* as your variable name -that's not a good practice.

```py
# L is your list...
# val = 'c'

for idx, lst in enumerate(L):
    if val in lst:
        print(f' which sub-list: {idx}, the value position: {lst.index(val)}')

# Output:
# which sub-list: 0, the value position: 2

# running with val is `g`
# >>> which sub-list: 2, the value position: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop over the rows. Then check whether the searched character is in the row before trying to get its index.

```
for i, row in enumerate(list):
    if 'c' in row:
        print(i, row.index('c'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(list.index("c"))` does not work, as `list` as a list containing lists, not chars. I assume you are looking for coordinates as an answer; something like

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        if (list[i][j] == 'c'):
            print(f"c at list[{i}][{j}]")
```

will give you that.

As for your second suggestion, you need to call `index` to `list[0]`, so:

```
list[0].index('c')
```

Comment: While `in` is more elegant, in terms of complexity `in` is equivalent to an iteration (O(n)). If you want to find an index, the combination of `in` and `index` is more expensive than an iteration. (assuming that the iterations stops when it finds answers, here I let it run since OP did not mention whether they want to know one or all occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDnI1.png)

```
def find_char(list, char):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list[i])):
            if list[i][j] == char:
               return (i, j)
            return None

       list = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
       char = "c"
       position = find_char(list, char)
       found = ""
       if position:
          found = list[position[0]][position[1]]
       else:
          print(f"Character {char} not found in list")

       print(found)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).